# Java synchronization

Tags: java, synchronization

I am bit stuck here, I have to have edit this code so that a train must wait in front of the tunnel lock for a train to come in the opposite direction to exit before it can enter the tunnel, i have to use java built in synchronisation condition

```
public synchronized void useTunnelLock(Train train)
{


    System.out.println(train + " " + train.getDirection());
    System.out.println(train + " exiting lock");
    try
    {
        // occupy tunnel lock for 5s
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    // swap direction of tunnel lock
    direction = (direction == ASCENDING)? DESCENDING : ASCENDING;
}
```

Comment: 1) sounds like homework 2) what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it would be reasonable to use a [semaphore](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

Comment: I was thinking before the try,using a if or while statement to say if the train is ascending train waiting to descend wait or if train is descending telling the train waiting to ascend to wait, but there is 8 trains 4 ascending and 4 descending and only 1 train is allowed to go one way at a time

Comment: This is just a side thought but, is it only one train at a time or can it be any number of trains going the same direction that can pass through?

Comment: This is a pretty good example of how you can use a semaphore: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/semaphores.html